# What is the point of "protected" word in Java if it gives you the same access rights as default access?

Tags: java, default, encapsulation, protected

Can anybody explain me why do we need "protected" word?
If I understand correctly,

> default access: available in classes within the same package.
>
> protected access: default access in same package + available to inherited classes
> (sub-classes) in any package. Basically, we get the same
> default access in same package.

So when should I use it? Just for the style of your code? To mark it that you are going to work with it from perspective of inheritance?
Thank you.

```
package firstPack;

public class First {
    protected int a;
    protected void Chat(){
        System.out.println("Here I am");
    }
}
```

```
package secondPack;  

import firstPack.First;

public class Second extends First{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        First f=new First();
//      f.Chat();
//      System.out.println(f.a);
    }
}
```

I used this code to test it. It didn't work.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with your test code is that you ware trying to access protected members of `First`  class instance and via `First` class reference. Notice that since `Second` class is not in the same package as `First` one it doesn't have access to protected fields of **any** instance of base class, but have access to its own fields inherited from `First` class (which includes `protected` ones). So something like

```
First f = new First();
f.chat();//chat is protected in base class.
```

will not compile in `Second` class, but something like

```
public void test() {
    a = 1;  // have access to inherited protected field or 
    chat(); // methods of base class 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Second f = new Second();
    f.chat();
    System.out.println(f.a);
}
```

is OK since Second class have access to its inherited members.

Notice that code in `main` method works only because it is placed inside `Second` class since only derived classes or classes in the same package as `First` have access to its protected members. So if this code will be placed inside other class like

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Second f = new Second();
        f.chat();
        System.out.println(f.a);
    }
}
```

it will not compile (no access to protected members because `Test` doesn't extend or is not in same package as `First`).

Answer (score 2):

`protected` means visible to *all* sub-classes, not just those in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

The `protected` modifier:  Accessed by other classes in the **same package** or any 
subclasses of the class in which they are referred (i.e. same package or different package).

*Reference*

[image]